# pynput Keyboard Listener Doesn't Work Globally in MacOS X

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pynput, macos-monterey

I am using pynput to record keystrokes on MacOS Monterey, and I fixed the issue where it says "This process isn't trusted ..." for when I'm logged in, but on the login screen it still shows. I understand that MacOS is blocking this to prevent a keylogger from getting your password, but I actually *want* it to work there.

Here's my code if it helps:

```
#! usr/bin/python3
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
    listener.join()

# This code simply writes the keystrokes to a file.
```

**The reason I want this to work on the login screens is because the program stops itself once MacOS stops the pynput process because it's not trusted.** I want the program to keep running.

So, how can I get this code to work globally on MacOS, throughout all users, and even in the login screen?

Comment: How did you launch the python program ?

Comment: source env/bin/activate, and ran with python3. Any other/better way to run will be accepted